# How to follow _ after $ in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command

I have a shell script that need to use a variable following a dash to generate the file names.Here is what I did:

```
var="5"
echo "filename$var_something.txt"
```

However, it always output error, because the script treats $var_something as a variable.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo "filename${var}_something.txt"` use braces to delimit your variable name.